# ImageButton Click Action Android

Tags: android, click, imagebutton

I've stored the imagebutton info in an xml. It's image path,width,height and so on. 
But since there are multiple images I want to store data for each imagebutton while it's clicked. for example, if there are two buttons named male and female, i want to set String value = "male"; if male image button is clicked. But it did not work. Can somebody help me?

```
 public void AddAllImageButtons() throws IOException {
        AbsoluteLayout Layout = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
        Layout.addView(btn);
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams absParams = (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams) btn
                .getLayoutParams();

        absParams.x = x;
        absParams.y = y;
        btn.setLayoutParams(absParams);
        btn.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        btn.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open(path)));

        if(type.equals("imagebutton")){
        if(elementId.equals("female")){
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gender = elementId;
                GenerateAlertBoxes(gender);
            }
        });
}
```

Id is the image button id which is created in xml file.
 AlertBox text does not show "female" for this example.

Comment: your aproach is wrong, check some tutorials for such basic stuff - http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-example/

Comment: Your question is not phrased clearly enough. Like Mihail says, I think you should read some basic android tutorials before you go any further.

Comment: yes you are right, but i am not creating the image buttons as examples in the link. There are 5 image buttons and by reading their weight,height,image path from another xml in assets folder, buttons are created.

Comment: Is it still not clear?

Comment: your question is still not clear - where are defined the `type` and `elementId` variable??

Comment: type and elementId comes from xml which is parsed

Comment: ImageButton information x,y,width,elementId type comes from xml. type is imagebutton , elementId is whether it's male or female

Comment: "<element>" + "<id>male</id>"
    + "<type>imagebutton</type>" + "<path>man.png</path>"
    + "<text></text>" + "<x>50</x>" + "<y>75</y>" + "</element>"

Comment: I think you did not get my question. ok , thnxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can setTag("value") to set the value in the ImageButton btn and on the onclick event you can use getTag() function to retrieve the value and set it to gender.

use btn.setTag(elementid); whenever you add a btn to the layout.......

inside btn.setOnClickListener you can write v.getTag().toString() to get the value and set it to gender...... 

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gender = v.getTag().toString();
                GenerateAlertBoxes(gender);
            }
        });
```